# "After paste" event in CkEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, paste

Is it possible to intercept an event that is fired after pasting something in CkEditor?

I know that it's possible to use the `paste` event, that is fired *before* that some content is inserted in the editor; what I'm looking for is an event that is fired *after* inserting contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution in [this page](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Paste-event) of the official forum of CkEditor.

The event I was looking for is provided by the framework, and it is called `afterPaste`.

You can use it as the following example shows:

```
editor.on('afterPaste', function (event) {
    //Do what you want
});
```

Comment: Hey. Anybody knows, how to get the last value pasted? Thanks